# how to multiply a input text value by selecting from option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering how can I multiply an element value by selecting from  tag?

for example I have a `<input type='text' value='9'>` text tag or `<span>9</span>` tag and I want to multiply its value by selecting option tag
likewise

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">1/month</option>
    <option value="2">2/month</option>
    <option value="3">3/month</option>
    <option value="6">6/month</option>
    <option value="12">12/month</option>
</select>
```

and i also want to this below option values to assign the above options tag when selected any of this below options, like example when `<option value="9">basic</option>` selected the above first option value should look like this `<option value="9">1/month</option>` and next so on,and its value should multiply as `if 1/month 9*1` `if 2/month 9*2` `if 3/month 9*3` `if 6/month 9*6` and so on.And i also want to show these option values into input tag or span tag.
any idea how to do this?
many thanks in advance.

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="9">basic</option>
  <option value="19">standard</option>
  <option value="29">professional</option>
  <option value="59">enterprise</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Things you need to know, `change` event, `data` attributes, `.next()` function and `.text()` function

Your html,

```
<select name="test" id="test">
    <option value="1">1/month</option>
    <option value="2">2/month</option>
    <option value="3">3/month</option>
    <option value="6">6/month</option>
    <option value="12">12/month</option>
</select>

<span data-val="9">9</span>
```

JS,

```
$('#test').change(function(){
   var span = $(this).next('span');
   span.text(span.data('val') * parseInt(this.value,10))
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LNdWs/)

Comment: well its perfect, and what is the next solution?
like when select below options tag the above options value should change corresponding to below options.

Comment: @Mr.beginner what do you mean by next solution..?

Comment: I also want to assign below option tags value to above option tag value when select any of the below option tag

Comment: like when `<option value="19">standard</option>` selected the `<option value="2">2/month</option>` value should look like this `<option value="19">2/month</option>`

Comment: @Mr.beginner i dont know why you are asking that, but you can do that with `$(this).find(':selected').attr('value',span.text())`. Place this code as the last line.

Comment: ok let me try it, if it will helpful I will be very thankful to you.